# Copy File to Clipboard

Tags: command-line-interface, copy, nix, clipboard

Simple Question that I just realized would be very useful.

Under Linux (or really any 'nix environment) is it possible from the command line (or by other fashions, but primarily command line) to copy a file to the clipboard?  Any example of this working would be appreciated but the best answer would be a general case in which this is possible across multiple 'nix environments (I'm running Fedora 10 atm if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want [`xclip`](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xclip/).

Usage:

```
xclip -t clipboard somefile
```

or an example using [using pipes](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe):

```
grep "needle" myfile.txt | xclip -t clipboard
```

Without the `-t clipboard` the data will go [to PRIMARY selection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139193/209677).

Comment: +1: Awesome! I figured there was a program like that around, but didn't know the name :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you in X? Or text-only?

If you're in text mode, it's dead simple if you're using screen (which is awesome):

```
<C-A>:readbuf /path/to/file
```

To paste:

```
<C-A>]
```